# Javascript automatic function execution

Tags: javascript

If i'm writing event in this way, action executes when it should:

```
 document.getElementById('myElem').onmousedown = (e) => {
     console.log('fired!')
    }
```

But if i'm writing same stuff in other way, action executes when page is loaded, once:

```
let HandleEvent = (event) => {
 console.log('fired!')
}
document.getElementById('myElem').onmousedown = HandleEvent(event)
```

**UPD:**
Ofcourse it is just example, `HandleEvent` function will have much more complex logic.

My questions is:

1. Why?
2. How to make it work properly?

Comment: `onmousedown` expects a `function` reference, but what you're passing is the returned value of the function (which is `undefined`) because you're *invoking* it. Try `document.getElementById('myElem').onmousedown = HandleEvent` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('myElem').onmousedown = HandleEvent;
```

Would do what you want; you should not execute the handler when assigning it. You should just assign the function reference.

Then you can also assign it as the onload handler, or even call it yourself (if you are not relying on the event object)

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById('myElem').onmousedown = HandleEvent;
```

To pass additional arguments you could use bind:

```
document.getElementById('myElem').onmousedown = HandleEvent.bind(null, argument1, argument2);
```

...or you could use a factory function:

```
document.getElementById('myElem').onmousedown = createHandler();

function createHandler() {
  var a = calculateA();
  var b = calculateA();
  return function handleEvent() {
     //use a and/or b
  };
}
```

There are other ways too. Precise code will depend on your use case.

Comment: how can i pass additional params to function?

Comment: @Src `Function.prototype.bind`

Comment: @Src: That wasn't your question. Ben answered the question you asked. (And you can readily find an answer to *that* question by searching SO, where it's been very, very thoroughly answerd.)

Comment: Function.bind or wrap it in a another function that calls HandleEvent passing it the parameters you want

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much! I already accepted answer before you edited the question, so i think it would not be right to re accept it. sorry :\

Comment: @src if this post answers your question better, feel free to change the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `event`.

```
let HandleEvent = (event) => 'fired!';
document.getElementById('myElem').onmousedown = HandleEvent
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the event

```
let HandleEvent = (event) => {
 console.log('fired!')
}
document.getElementById('myElem').onmousedown = HandleEvent
```

Comment: Remove the event is not a very good description of what removing the parentheses does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an attribute

```
let HandleEvent = (event) => {
 console.log('fired!')
}
document.getElementById('myElem').onmousedown = HandleEvent.bind(attribute)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did was assigning the result of HandleEvent() to the event, instead you should assign the function to it.

Correct statement:

document.getElementById('myElem').onmousedown = HandleEvent;